# SQL query to return unique top row for each group

Tags: sql

Trying to write a query that would return a unique record for each systems name.

The existing query returns several records for each systemName since there are multiple version of the same product present. 
I am able to sort by version number but would like to be able to only keep the top version number for each system.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.sysName
      ,v.groupName
      ,a.versionNumb
      ,b.userName
  FROM table1 AS a
  INNER JOIN table2 AS v ON v.sID = a.sID 
  INNER JOIN table3 AS b ON v.sID = b.sID
  WHERE a.versionNumb LIKE '10.%'
    AND v.groupName LIKE '%' + @groupVar
  ORDER BY a.versionNumb DESC
```

Tried using ROW_NUMBER() to sort and return the row value but I'm still not 100% on getting the proper data extracted.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you selecting the "versionNumb" column? What are you expecting it to be in case when there are multiple records for one system name, but only one record should be present in as a result?

Comment: Would you mind posting a snippet of your tables?

Comment: machine1 group 3 softwareVersion10.123 user2 ----
machine1 group 3 softwareVersion10.111 user2 ----
machine2 group1 softwareVersion10.111 user4 ----
machine2 group1 softwareVersion10.107 user4 ----
machine3 group 1 softwareVersion10.123 user5 ----
machine4 group 2 softwareVersion10.111 user1 ---- 
machine4 group 2 softwareVersion10.100 user1

Comment: sorry about the crappy formatting but in any case this is what the data looks like

Answer (score 0):

Just use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT v.sysName,
       v.groupName,
       MAX(a.versionNumb) as versionNumb,
       b.userName
FROM table1 AS a
INNER JOIN table2 AS v ON v.sID = a.sID 
INNER JOIN table3 AS b ON v.sID = b.sID
WHERE a.versionNumb LIKE '10.%'
AND v.groupName LIKE '%' + @groupVar
GROUP BY v.sysName, v.groupName, b.userName
```

I removed your `DISTINCT` because it's redundant with a `GROUP BY`

Comment: You should remove the last line I guess: "ORDER BY a.versionNumb DESC"

Comment: @VadymPechenoha Good call

Comment: Trying to use GROUP BY instead of ORDER BY, I keep on getting the following:
--Column xyz is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i'm about to use the group by feature if I remove the b.username and v.groupName entries from the select query but would really like the info in there are well.

Comment: @SamWagner Can you post your whole query?  Need to make sure all the columns you are selecting are also in your group by (except for those with aggregation, like `MAX(a.versionNumb)`)

Comment: @SamWagner Side note, you can still use your `ORDER BY` if you want it.. just add it after the `GROUP BY`

Comment: NM, that worked... I was missing one of the field in the GROUP BY.... !!! THANKS!

Comment: @SamWagner Np, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query to GROUP BY by system name and after JOIN to take all information you need

```
SELECT d.sysName, max (d.versionNumb)
  FROM (select * from table1 AS a
  INNER JOIN table2 AS v ON v.sID = a.sID) as d
Group by d.sysName
```